# Oracle/Toad Active Pane Setting

Tags: oracle, window, settings, toad

On TOAD for oracle, there is a bar at the bottom where your active windows (be it an sql editor, schema browser or SQL modeller window) are displayed. I have just moved office and it now only displays the active window and none of the other windows...

any of you toad guru's know how to get it to display all the windows?

Toad version 7.5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Options and

1. uncheck "Allow docking and hiding....".
2. check "Show Window titles..." and "Show connect strings...".

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Toad Options-> Toolbars/Menus--> Toolbars , Select the Visual Style: Standard under Display Section and Apply the changes. That should do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't come across that problem, so just guessing:

Check the options under Toolbars/Menus -> Toolbars -> "Display", e.g. "Multi-line Window Bar", "Show window titles on Window Bar"

Perhaps it has been reduced in size or can't fit in the available area?

Comment: Had a look through this...it must be the size, It shows which Schema I am on, but the bar above the schema bar where the window tabs are is missing. Doh!